# How do I exclude ActionBar when using Frame tag in a TabView?

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

#### My Problem

I am using a simple TabView on a particular page.

```
<Page class="page" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

    <ActionBar class="action-bar">
        <!-- 
        Use the NavigationButton as a side-drawer button in Android
        because ActionItems are shown on the right side of the ActionBar
        -->
        <NavigationButton ios:visibility="collapsed" icon="res://menu" tap="onDrawerButtonTap"></NavigationButton>
        <!-- 
        Use the ActionItem for IOS with position set to left. Using the
        NavigationButton as a side-drawer button in iOS is not possible,
        because its function is to always navigate back in the application.
        -->
        <ActionItem icon="res://navigation/menu" android:visibility="collapsed"
            tap="onDrawerButtonTap" ios.position="left">
        </ActionItem>
        <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Browse"></Label>
    </ActionBar>

    <TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
        <TabViewItem title="first tab">
            <Frame defaultPage="home/home-page"></Frame>
        </TabViewItem>
        <TabViewItem title="2222 tab">
            <Frame defaultPage="search/search-page"></Frame>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView>

</Page>
```

as you see, when we arrive at this page, we are presented with bottom tabs. But the problem occurs when we click on one of the tabs.

What's happening is, it's importing the entire page including the Title Bar.

**Screenshot of Error**

[image: Title Bar Erroneously Imported]

### Ideal Solution

I would like to have be able to import the page in my TabView using the Frame tag, but exclude the ActionBar when doing so.

When we NavigateTo the page directly, I DO WANT the action bar to show up.

Is this possible? If so, could you point me in the right direction? Here is my code failing miserably...

#### [Online Demo in Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=knkQ9r&v=3)

Thanks for looking,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the `actionBarHidden` property to `false` on the `Page` you do not want action bar to appear.

If you don't want the action bar on the entire `Frame`, then set `actionBarVisibility` to `never` on the `Frame` itself.

```
    <TabView>
        <TabViewItem title="first tab">
            <Frame defaultPage="home/home-page" actionBarVisibility="never"></Frame>
        </TabViewItem>
        <TabViewItem title="2222 tab">
            <Frame defaultPage="search/search-page" actionBarVisibility="never"></Frame>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView>
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=knkQ9r&v=4)